# Why is my tree grammar ambiguous?

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I'm a little confused. I have a grammar that works well and matches my language just as I want it to. Recently, I added a couple rules to the grammar and in the process of converting the new grammar rules to the tree grammar I am getting some strange errors. The first error I was getting was that the tree grammar was ambiguous.

The errors I received were:

```
[10:53:16] warning(200): ShiroDefinitionPass.g:129:17: 
Decision can match input such as "'subjunctive node'" using multiple alternatives: 5, 6

As a result, alternative(s) 6 were disabled for that input
[10:53:16] warning(200): ShiroDefinitionPass.g:129:17: 
Decision can match input such as "PORT_ASSIGNMENT" using multiple alternatives: 2, 6
```

and about 10 more similar errors.

I can't tell why the tree grammar is ambiguous. It was fine before I added the sNode, subjunctDeclNodeProd, subjunctDecl, and subjunctSelector rules.

My grammar is:

```
grammar Shiro;

options{
    language = Java;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    output=AST;
}

tokens{
    NEGATION;
    STATE_DECL;
    PORT_DECL;
    PORT_INIT;
    PORT_ASSIGNMENT;
    PORT_TAG;
    PATH;
    PORT_INDEX;
    EVAL_SELECT;
    SUBJ_SELECT;
    SUBJ_NODE_PROD;
    ACTIVATION;
    ACTIVATION_LIST;
    PRODUCES;
}

shiro   :   statement+
    ;   

statement
    :   nodestmt
    |   sNode 
    |   graphDecl
    |   statestmt
    |   collection
    |   view
    |   NEWLINE!
    ;

view    :   'view' IDENT mfName IDENT -> ^('view' IDENT mfName IDENT)
    ;

collection
    :   'collection' IDENT orderingFunc path 'begin' NEWLINE
            (collItem)+ NEWLINE?
        'end'
        -> ^('collection' IDENT orderingFunc path collItem+)
    ;

collItem:   IDENT -> IDENT
    ;

orderingFunc
    :   IDENT -> IDENT
    ;

statestmt
    :   'state' stateName 'begin' NEWLINE
        stateHeader
        'end' -> ^(STATE_DECL stateName stateHeader)
    ;

stateHeader
    :   (stateTimeStmt | stateCommentStmt | stateParentStmt | stateGraphStmt | activationPath | NEWLINE!)+  
    ;

stateTimeStmt
    :   'Time' time -> ^('Time' time)
    ;

stateCommentStmt
    :   'Comment' comment -> ^('Comment' comment)   
    ;

stateParentStmt
    :   'Parent' stateParent -> ^('Parent' stateParent)
    ;

stateGraphStmt
    :   'Graph' stateGraph -> ^('Graph' stateGraph)
    ;

stateName
    :   IDENT
    ;

time    :   STRING_LITERAL  
    ;

comment :   STRING_LITERAL
    ;

stateParent
    :   IDENT
    ;

stateGraph
    :   IDENT
    ;

activationPath
    :   l=activation ('.'^ (r=activation | activationList))*
    ;

activationList
    :   '<' activation (',' activation)* '>' -> ^(ACTIVATION_LIST activation+)
    ;

activation
    :   c=IDENT ('[' v=IDENT ']')? -> ^(ACTIVATION $c ($v)?)
    ;

graphDecl
    :   'graph' IDENT 'begin' NEWLINE
        graphLine+
        'end'
        -> ^('graph' IDENT graphLine+)
    ;

graphLine
    :   nodeProduction | portAssignment | NEWLINE!
    ;

nodeInternal
    :   (nodeProduction 
        | portAssignment 
        | portstmt 
        | nodestmt 
        | sNode 
        | NEWLINE!)+
    ;

nodestmt 
    :   'node'^ IDENT ('['! activeSelector ']'!)? 'begin'! NEWLINE!
        nodeInternal
        'end'!
    ;

sNode
:   'subjunctive node'^ IDENT '['! subjunctSelector ']'! 'begin'! NEWLINE!
        (subjunctDeclNodeProd | subjunctDecl | NEWLINE!)+
        'end'!
    ;

subjunctDeclNodeProd
    :   l=IDENT '->' r=IDENT 'begin' NEWLINE
        nodeInternal
        'end' -> ^(SUBJ_NODE_PROD $l $r nodeInternal )
    ;

subjunctDecl
    :   'subjunct'^ IDENT ('['! activeSelector ']'!)? 'begin'! NEWLINE!
        nodeInternal
        'end'!
    ;

subjunctSelector
    :   IDENT -> ^(SUBJ_SELECT IDENT)
    ;

activeSelector  
    :   IDENT -> ^(EVAL_SELECT IDENT)
    ;

nodeProduction
    :   path ('->'^ activationPath )+ NEWLINE!
    ;

portAssignment
    :   path '(' mfparams ')' NEWLINE -> ^(PORT_ASSIGNMENT path mfparams)
    ;   

portDecl
    :   portType portName mfName -> ^(PORT_DECL ^(PORT_TAG portType) portName mfName)
    ;

portDeclInit
    :   portType portName mfCall -> ^(PORT_INIT ^(PORT_TAG portType) portName mfCall)
    ;

portstmt    
    :   (portDecl | portDeclInit ) NEWLINE!
    ;   

portName 
    :   IDENT
    ;

portType:   'port'
    |   'eval'
    ;

mfCall  :   mfName '(' mfparams ')' -> ^(mfName mfparams)
    ;

mfName  :   IDENT
    ;

mfparams:   expression(',' expression)* -> expression+
    ;

// Path
path    :   (IDENT)('.' IDENT)*('[' pathIndex ']')? -> ^(PATH IDENT+ pathIndex?)
    ;

pathIndex
    :   portIndex -> ^(PORT_INDEX portIndex)
    ;

portIndex
    :   ( NUMBER |STRING_LITERAL )
    ;

// Expressions
term    :   path
    |   '(' expression ')' -> expression
    |   NUMBER
    |   STRING_LITERAL
    ;

unary   :   ('+'^ | '-'^)* term

    ;

mult    :   unary (('*'^ | '/'^ | '%'^) unary)*
    ;

add     
    :   mult (( '+'^ | '-'^ ) mult)*
    ;

expression
    :   add (( '|'^ ) add)*
    ;

// LEXEMES
STRING_LITERAL
    :   '"' .* '"'
    ;

NUMBER  :   DIGIT+ ('.'DIGIT+)?
    ;

IDENT   :   (LCLETTER | UCLETTER | DIGIT)(LCLETTER | UCLETTER | DIGIT|'_')*
    ;

COMMENT
        :       '//' ~('\n'|'\r')*  {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' NEWLINE?{$channel=HIDDEN;}
        ;

WS
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;}
    ;

NEWLINE :   '\r'? '\n'
    ;

fragment
LCLETTER 
    :   'a'..'z'
    ;

fragment
UCLETTER:   'A'..'Z'
    ;   

fragment
DIGIT   :   '0'..'9'
    ;
```

My tree grammar for the section looks like:

```
tree grammar ShiroDefinitionPass;

options{
    tokenVocab=Shiro;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

shiro
    :   statement+

    ;   

statement   
    :   nodestmt
    |   sNode
    |   graphDecl
    |   statestmt
    |   collection
    |   view
    ;

view    :   ^('view' IDENT mfName IDENT)
    ;

collection
    :   ^('collection' IDENT orderingFunc path collItem+)
    ;

collItem:   IDENT
    ;

orderingFunc
    :   IDENT
    ;

statestmt
    :   ^(STATE_DECL stateHeader)
    ;

stateHeader
    :   (stateTimeStmt | stateCommentStmt | stateParentStmt| stateGraphStmt | activation )+     
    ;

stateTimeStmt
    :   ^('Time' time)
    ;

stateCommentStmt
    :   ^('Comment' comment)    
    ;

stateParentStmt
    :   ^('Parent' stateParent)
    ;

stateGraphStmt
    :   ^('Graph' stateGraph)
    ;

stateName
    :   IDENT
    ;

time    :   STRING_LITERAL  
    ;

comment :   STRING_LITERAL
    ;

stateParent
    :   IDENT
    ;

stateGraph
    :   IDENT
    ;

activationPath
    :   l=activation ('.' (r=activation | activationList))*
    ;

activationList
    :   ^(ACTIVATION_LIST activation+)
    ;

activation
    :   ^(ACTIVATION IDENT IDENT?)
    ;

// Graph Declarations
graphDecl
    :   ^('graph' IDENT graphLine+)
    ;

graphLine
    :   nodeProduction
    |   portAssignmen
    ;
// End Graph declaration

nodeInternal
    :   (nodeProduction
        |portAssignment
        |portstmt
        |nodestmt
        |sNode )+
    ;

nodestmt
    :   ^('node' IDENT activeSelector? nodeInternal)    
    ;

sNode
    :   ^('subjunctive node' IDENT subjunctSelector (subjunctDeclNodeProd | subjunctDecl)*)
    ;

subjunctDeclNodeProd
    :   ^(SUBJ_NODE_PROD IDENT IDENT nodeInternal+ )
    ;

subjunctDecl
    :   ^('subjunct' IDENT activeSelector? nodeInternal )
    ;

subjunctSelector
    :   ^(SUBJ_SELECT IDENT)
    ;

activeSelector returns 
    :   ^(EVAL_SELECT IDENT)
    ;

nodeProduction
    :   ^('->' nodeProduction)
    |   path 
    ;

portAssignment
    :   ^(PORT_ASSIGNMENT path)  
    ;   

// Port Statement
portDecl
    :   ^(PORT_DECL ^(PORT_TAG portType) portName mfName) 
    ;

portDeclInit
    :   ^(PORT_INIT ^(PORT_TAG portType) portName mfCall)
    ;

portstmt    
    :   (portDecl | portDeclInit)
    ;   

portName
    :   IDENT 
    ;

portType returns 
    :   'port' | 'eval'
    ;


mfCall
    :   ^(mfName mfparams) 
    ;

mfName
    :   IDENT
    ;

mfparams  
    :   (exps=expression)+
    ;   

// Path
path
    :   ^(PATH (id=IDENT)+ (pathIndex)? )
    ;

pathIndex 
    :   ^(PORT_INDEX portIndex)
    ;

portIndex
    :   ( NUMBER 
        |STRING_LITERAL
        )
    ;

// Expressions
expression
    :   ^('+' op1=expression op2=expression) 
    |   ^('-' op1=expression op2=expression) 
    |   ^('*' op1=expression op2=expression) 
    |   ^('/' op1=expression op2=expression)
    |   ^('%' op1=expression op2=expression) 
    |   ^('|' op1=expression op2=expression)
    |   NUMBER 
    |   path
    ;
```

Comment: IMO, there's too much code/grammar to go through. I might consider giving your grammars a go through ANTLRWorks, but you'd need to post 2 clean (no custom code!) grammar files I can simply copy and paste and see the errors you're seeing. The snippets of your grammars are missing too much for me to test.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry about that. It was sloppiness on my part. I have removed the custom code.

Comment: No problem, but it's not *just* the embedded code, I would have removed it myself if that was the only thing (I'm lazy, but not *that* lazy :)). I see the `tokens { ... }` block is missing, the `activationPath` rule is missing (and maybe more?). What I ask of you is to post 2 grammars (combined and tree) that need no editing at all: so starting from grammar definition. That is not only helpful for (lazy) people like me, but also ensures I see exactly what you see.

Comment: Okay, let me know if this works for you. You now have my complete grammar.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out the answer I posted? If it wasn't what you were looking for (or if you solved the problem yourself), please let me know. I hate having "dud" answers (no comments, no votes for or against, no other answers, ...) floating around, especially when the problem is about something that's broken rather than something theoretical. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I left for a conference just after the question was posted. Yes, your answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tree grammar, here is the declaration of rule `nodeInternal`:

```
  nodeInternal
    :  (nodeProduction
       |portAssignment
       |portstmt
       |nodestmt
       |sNode)+
    ;
```

And here is your declaration of rule `subjunctDeclNodeProd`:

```
   subjunctDeclNodeProd
    :   ^(SUBJ_NODE_PROD IDENT IDENT nodeInternal+ )
    ;
```

When `subjunctDeclNodeProd` is being processed, ANTLR doesn't know how to process an input such as this, with two `PATH` children:

```
^(SUBJ_NODE_PROD IDENT IDENT ^(PATH IDENT) ^(PATH IDENT))
```

Should it follow rule `nodeInternal` once and process `nodeProduction, nodeProduction` or should it follow `nodeInternal` twice and process `nodeProduction` each time?

Consider rewriting `subjunctDeclNodeProd` without the `+`:

```
   subjunctDeclNodeProd
    :   ^(SUBJ_NODE_PROD IDENT IDENT nodeInternal)
    ;
```

I think that will take care of the problem.